# Add a member to Microsoft Teams using Graph API and delegated permissions

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to simply add a member (who is already in the organization) to a specific Microsoft Team. The observerID is the id of the the member that I want to add and teamID is is the ID of the specific Team. I am using delegated permission with TeamMembers.ReadWrite.All enabled.
My code looks like this:

```
            string json = $@"
            {{
              ""@odata.type"": ""#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember"",
              ""roles"": [""member""],
              ""user@odata.bind"": ""https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users({observerID})""
            }}";
            
            var body = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            Console.WriteLine("Add observer");
            return await protectedApiCallHelper.CallWebApiAsync(WebApiUrlTeams + teamID + "/members", accessToken, body);
```

```
public async Task<JObject> CallWebApiAsync(string webApiUrl, string accessToken, HttpContent content)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            {
                var defaultRequestHeaders = HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
                if (defaultRequestHeaders.Accept == null || !defaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Any(m => m.MediaType == "application/json"))
                {
                    HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                }
                defaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.PostAsync(webApiUrl, content);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;
                    return result;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

My problem is that the http call fails with the status code 400; 'Bad Request'. I have tried again and again to find any issues with my call but I can't seem to find the problem. When I Console.WriteLine the json I use for the body it looks like this:

```
            {
              "odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
              "roles": ["member"],
              "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users(d52c2663-1c41-401b-8015-1216f0e68960)"
            }
```

And the url looks like: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/a9f9ac33-fba5-4ce2-9515-8c498c70af85/members" and when I try the call through Postman it still returns a error code 400.

Does anyone have any insight on what might be wrong?

Comment: Could you please share the whole error response with Requestid and timestamp.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, this error is very simple. Reporting 400 is usually a parameter error. Your json file is missing the special symbols `@` and `"`. I tested it locally and worked for me.

[image]